# Does SZS equal Z?

Tags: quantum-gate

I am completely new to quantum computing and playing [QuantAttack](https://qniapp.github.io/quantattack/). While playing, I found something strange: SZS turns into Z.

According to [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate) that the game recommends reading, SZS must disappear because:

$$
SZS = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & i\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & i\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = I
$$

Is there some weird quantum thing I missed, or is it just a game bug?

Answer (score 2):

SZS is not equal to Z, it is equal to identity matrix as mentioned in the article. SZ$S^{\dagger}$ is equal to Z ,where $S^{\dagger}$ is the conjugate transpose of S gate.

This can be proved by matrix multiplication
$$
SZS^{\dagger}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & i\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -i\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} = Z
$$

You can check the below link for more info about S and S dagger gates
https://www.quantum-inspire.com/kbase/s-gate/

Comment: Thank you! I asked the game developer and they said it's indeed a game bug.